No property 'searchSimilar' found for type 'Items' [elasticSearch with spring boot]
I'm using elasticSearch running on a docker container with Spring boot.
Below is the detail of the problem.
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.searchSimilar(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String[],org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository.searchSimilar(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String[],org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable); No property 'searchSimilar' found for type 'Items'

Below is the Item table
@Document(indexName = "itemindex")
public class Items{
@Id
@UuidGenerator
  private String id;

    @PrePersist
    public void onPrePersist() {
    
            if (created == null) {
            created = new Date();  // Set creation date
        }
    }
    
    
    @Column
    @Field(type=FieldType.Text,name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column
     @Field(type=FieldType.Text,name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column
      @Field(type=FieldType.Float,name="basePrice")
    private BigDecimal basePrice;

     @OneToMany(
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Bid> bids; 

    @Column
    private String currency;

    @ManyToOne
    @Field(type=FieldType.Nested,name="creator")
    private UserModel creator;
    
    @ElementCollection
     private List<String> pictures;
    

    @ManyToOne
     @Field(type=FieldType.Nested,name="organization")
    private Organization organization;

    @Column
    private Date expiryTime;

        @Column
    private String category;

    @Column
    @Field(type=FieldType.Date,name="created")
    private Date created;

     @Column
    private Date updated;


    
    @Column
    @Field(type=FieldType.Boolean,name="isDeleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;



  @PreUpdate
  protected void onUpdate() {
    updated = new Date();
  }


   public Boolean addBid(Bid bid) {
        if (!this.bids.contains(bid)) {
            this.bids.add(bid);
            bid.setItem(this);
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
      return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    
}

Repository interface below
public interface ItemElasticSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Items,String>{
    
}

How it's called
    @Autowired
   private ItemElasticSearchRepository itemElasticSearchRepository;
  ...
  @CacheEvict(value = "items", allEntries = true)  
    private Items saveItem(Items item){
        Items savedItem=itemRepository.save(item);
        itemElasticSearchRepository.save(item);
        return savedItem;
    }

I'm nowhere invoking the property searchSimilar directly. My initial thought is because I am using @CacheEvict and using the save method of the elastic repository it might conflict with methods inside itemElasticSearchRepository and methods inside itemRepository which extends JPARepository.

searchSimilar in Spring-Data Elasticsearch tries to utilize Elasticsearch's features for searching similarities. But Entities have to be correctly mapped for this to work in query creation.
Some of the Fields or Relationships particularly the @OneToMany, @ManyToOne or @ElementCollection saved in Items are relational and so incompatible with Elasticsearch as experienced for itemindex especially if mismatch vs what Items have.Notes regions that facilitate search similarity-related queries may be missing or incorrectly mapped within our index.Let’s consider improving support
for searchSimilar and the manner in which the index mappings are defined. Otherwise, things can be properly.
If you use "JpaRepository" and "ElasticsearchRepository" together, there may be conflicts. If an entity's lifecycle is different in these repositories, it may cause errors when saving or searching. Thus, it's key to keep the repositories separated with only the necessary operations delegated to each.
